# How change the placeholder size,color in html?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
```

In that input  field i need to change placeholder font-size,color for form

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: first try to search or find own way ..bro thn ask a question.

Comment: Simple search with google css placeholder

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your css file:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    red;
    font-size: 15px;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
     color:    red;
    font-size: 15px;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    red;
    font-size: 15px;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color:    red;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: duplicate answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Answer (score 0):

You can change placeholders style like this:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
   color: red;
   font-size: 12pt; 
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;
   font-size: 12pt; 
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
   color: red;
   font-size: 12pt; 
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;
   font-size: 12pt;
}
```

Comment: duplicate answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css